# xrpd service is not listening in RHEL 7

Tags: service, rhel7

I installed xrdp (according to the instructions on this post: [xrdp install instructions for RHEL 7](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/install-xrdp-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html#axzz3RfIhmB9K), enabled it, but the xrdp.service does not show that it's listening on port 3389.  What could be preventing it from listening? RHEL 7 is running in a VMware instance via port 22.

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11146/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3604/cupsd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12286/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31621/sshd: herrsch
tcp        0      0 172.19.0.123:22         172.19.0.143:5133       ESTABLISHED 31619/sshd: herrsch
tcp        0     36 172.19.0.123:22         172.19.0.143:5132       ESTABLISHED 31615/sshd: herrsch
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      11146/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      3604/cupsd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      12286/master
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN      31621/sshd: herrsch
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55502           0.0.0.0:*                           709/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           1339/dhclient
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           728/chronyd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           728/chronyd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           709/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46999           0.0.0.0:*                           1339/dhclient
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                728/chronyd
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                728/chronyd
udp6       0      0 :::4480                 :::*                                1339/dhclient
```

Comment: what is the output of 'systemctl status xrdp'?  I suspect it failed to start.